# Is there a way to detect the source of touch events on Android?

Tags: java, android, touch

I'm working on an application that needs to distinguish between physical touchscreen (hardware) touches and software simulated touches invoked by other application. Is there any way to do this without root access?

More info: I will be using this to detect if someone is using auto-clicker (auto-tapper?) software on their device to imitate activity in my application.

Bump: Still researching for an answer, I can't find any clear explanation online. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean "simulated touches invoked by other application"?

Comment: I mean tap simulations generated by apps like BotMaker (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frapeti.androidbotmaker&hl=en) or FRep (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.x0.strai.frep&hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Apps like BotMaker fake taps (that's why they require root, to be able to "inject" these fake taps) but it there's no concept of genuine vs fake taps in the Android so these injected will look equally genuine as any other tap to the apps.