# detect difference between simulated touches using the accessibilty services and normal touches

Tags: android

hey I just want to know if it is able to detect the difference between a simulated touch using the accessibilty services and a normal touch by the user?

I only found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952742/is-there-a-way-to-detect-the-source-of-touch-events-on-android?rq=1) stating it is not possible because the simulated touches are injected, thats also why the device has to be rooted. But for using the accessibilty services the device doesn't need to be rooted and still the touches can be simulated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can based on the pointer size.